# Set JavaScript object property by traversing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm looking for a way to walk an object based on an array and set the property for the last key on the object, for example:

```
var myArr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'quz' ];
var myVal = 'somethingElse';
var myObj = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            quz: 'something'
        }
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to change the value of the `quz` property to `somethingElse`. I've tried recursing but I feel like there's an easier way to do this.

I've been looking to lodash but can't find a method that seems to allow me to accomplish this.

Comment: so you already constructed such an object and just want to update the value?

Comment: correct, this is a default configuration object I'm looking to be able to override.

Comment: what about https://github.com/substack/js-traverse?

Comment: And you don't like a recursive solution... why, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could walk the object like this:

```js
var myArr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'quz' ],
    myVal = 'somethingElse',
    myObj = {
      foo: {
        bar: {
          quz: 'something'
        }
      }
    };

var obj= myObj;
do {
  obj= obj[myArr.shift()];
} while(myArr.length>1);

obj[myArr[0]]= 'somethingElse';

document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

---

**Update**

To address @Tomalak's concerns, and because you didn't specifically forbid a recursive solution, here's a reusable function with no side effects (other than changing the appropriate value of the object):

```
function setObj(obj, arr, val) {
  !(arr.length-1) && (obj[arr[0]]=val) ||
  setObj(obj[arr[0]], arr.slice(1), val);
}
```

Short-circuit evaluation prevents this from being an infinite loop.

**Snippet:**

```js
var myArr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'quz' ],
    myVal = 'somethingElse',
    myObj = {
      foo: {
        lorem: 'ignore me',
        bar: {
          quz: 'something'
        },
        other: {
          quz: 'leave me be'
        }
      }
    };

function setObj(obj, arr, val) {
  !(arr.length-1) && (obj[arr[0]]=val) ||
  setObj(obj[arr[0]], arr.slice(1), val);
}

setObj(myObj, myArr, 'somethingElse');

document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Comment: Actually, that is not really clean. It's not reusable and it modifies the original array, i.e. it has undesirable side effects.

Comment: @Tomalak, good point about modifying the original array.  See my update.

Comment: The function will throw for non-arrays and arrays of length 0. It throws when `obj` is null or undefined. Correct code > clever one-liners.

Comment: Throwing an error can be preferable to silently returning.  If the application is for medical, database, or missile-guidance purposes, it could be better to abort a program when invalid data is encountered.  Depending on the application, a `try ... catch ... finally` could handle invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'quz' ];
var myVal = 'somethingElse';
var myObj = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            quz: 'something'
        }
    }
};

function setHierarchcally(obj, keys, value) {
    if ( !(obj && keys && keys.length) ) return;
    if ( !obj.hasOwnProperty(keys[0]) ) return;

    if (keys.length === 1) {
        obj[keys[0]] = value;
    } else {
        setHierarchcally(obj[keys[0]], keys.slice(1, keys.length), value);
    }
}


setHierarchcally(myObj, myArr, myVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more general object traverse, you can tweak js-travserse a little bit, as demoed in this jsfiddle I just created:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/yxpx9wvL/10/


var leaves = new Traverse(myObj).reduce(function (acc, x) {
if (this.isLeaf) acc.push(x);
  return acc;
}, []);

alert(leaves[0]);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that contain no code, but only links to external pages. When the link breaks, the answer becomes unusable. And we are on a programming site, the code *belongs* into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`getPath` digs down into an object to get a property several levels deep based on an array of "paths", in your case MyArr. Use that to get the object containing the final property, and then just set it.

```
function getPath(obj, paths) {
  return paths.reduce(function(obj, path) { return obj[path]; }, obj);
}

function setLastProperty(obj, paths, val) {
  var final = paths.pop();
  getPath(obj, paths) [ final ] = val;
}

setLastProperty(MyObj, MyArray, MyVal);
```